# Как получить state в action?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Насколько допустимо прямо в экшене обращаться к `state.page` и там же увеличивает значения на 1? Возможно лучше сделать это через мутацию по аналогу с `setProducts()`? Правда от обращения напрямую никуда не деться. Я могу сделать через мутацию только увеличение значения на 1, верно?

```
// state
const state = {
    page: 1,
    all: []
}

// getters
const getters = {}

// actions
const actions = {
    getProducts ({ commit }, $state) {
        axios.get('/api/products', {
            params: {
              page: state.page,
            },
        }).then(({ data }) => {
            if (data.data.length) {
                commit('setProducts', data.data)
                state.page += 1
                $state.loaded();
            } else {
                $state.complete();
            }
        });
    }
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
    setProducts (state, products) {
        state.all.push(...products)
    }
}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) В action можно передать getters, чтобы обращение не было напрямую, а можно и сам state сунуть [(описание)](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/api/#actions)

```
// actions
const actions = {
    getProducts ({ commit, state }, $state) {
        axios.get('/api/products', {
            params: {
              page: state.page,
            },
        }).then(({ data }) => {
            if (data.data.length) {
                commit('setProducts', data.data);
                commit('incrementPage', 1);
                $state.loaded();
            } else {
                $state.complete();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2) Любые изменения state лучше делать через мутации, потому что:

- Они логируются стором
- Легко дебажатся
- Ну это бест практикс

А вообще все упирается в принятую концепцию разработки. Можно делать как угодно, если не планируете это никому показывать.